# Fix size of raster image fill in QGIS

Tags: qgis, style

When using Raster Image Fill in QGIS  I have no problem getting the image there but is there any way to make it stay one size within the shapefile rather than changing depending on how far you zoom in and out?

Answer (score 3):

Edit: I seem to have had misunderstood or misinterpreted the question when I replied to it a couple years ago.

the size should be in pixels or mms, not map units(the exact opposite of what I said), for this to happen. Then the size would be fixed, based on how it looks, not how it zooms in or out.
I hope this solves the problem

Previous answer:
You could define the size in map units instead of pixel or MMs.

Edit: Adding screenshots for more explanation

Here I am stylizing countries by using flag images as fills for the country polygons.
When you are stylizing the symbols you click on the drop down here (which I am guessing OP has already done)
[image]

and for the size you select map units here:
[image]

Comment: How is this done?

Comment: This still scales in and out for me