# Fix size of raster image fill in QGIS while zooming in and out

Tags: qgis

When using Raster Image Fill in QGIS I have no problem getting the image there but is there any way to make it stay one size within the shapefile rather than changing depending on how far you zoom in and out?

I have tried setting the size in pixels or mms, not map units, in order the keep the size while zooming in or out. I got this from from [Fix size of raster image fill in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/266624/fix-size-of-raster-image-fill-in-qgis) but it the solution is not working.

Python version: 3.9.5

QGIS version: 3.26.2-Buenos Aires Buenos Aires

Comment: I've not tried this but try changing the image width to `map units` from `mm` - you;ll probably have to adjust the value (a lot) to make is visible